# My new boss ask me about client's big boss hobby (B2B Account)

Tags: professionalism, communication, management, human-resources

I am a B2B sales, and my new boss is asking me to disclose all of my account key person's hobby, and the personality trait and put on the email. Is this proper? He thinks good sales should know it especially for their hobby so that he can get closer to the clients.

Comment: Why do you think it's improper?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with tell your boss what type of person the client is. After all, your boss will also want to maintain a good relationship with their clients/vendors. Close relationships between business make it much easier to make sales or get some additional benefits.

Comment: I thought this kind, like discuss someone’s privacy and which is not allowed. I feel better to provide to him now. Thanks!

Comment: Where in the world does it happen? It might conflict with European GDPR.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this proper?

Certainly. The more you know about your clients, the better.

Comment: I thought this consider as a client’s privacy, I should not disclose, especially on the email. But I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No problem with that, except the 'put it in an email' bit. That's too ephemeral for me. You should have a contact management system which has sections where you can store that information (plus the clients wife's details, kids, pets, etc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.